# How to show a radius in maps android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a eight different Longitude and latitude values in that any one value have longitude and latitude and remaining wont have values in that case I have to show a radius for that one value. Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: You mean you want to show circle around particular points on the map?

Comment: Yes, for which value i get the longitude and latitude values

Comment: clear your question with some more details

Comment: @Simple Plan: I'm getting values from server which have a 8 values in that I don't have a longitude and latitude values for 7 values. Only having for One value for that I have to show radius

Comment: then fetch only that value what is the problem on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GoogleMap` has method `addCircle` so your just need to call it with appropriate params:

```
GoogleMap map;
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
LatLng position = new LatLng(50, 50);
markerOptions.position(position);
Marker marker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);

Circle circle = map.addCircle(
    new CircleOptions()
        .center(position)
        .radius(100)
        .strokeWidth(0f)
        .fillColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.someColor))
);
```

Comment: it asking to give only one value

Comment: @HarishKoona who it is? If you don't give concrete errors nobody can  help you.